# Generate XLS File Using JSP at Server side

Tags: jsp, jxls

How to generate xls file using jsp at server side.?
I want to generate xls file at server side and store at specific location.

Comment: Have you tried to google for "java create xls file"?

Comment: You can't just "convert" an HTML file to Excel...you need to find a Java library for creating Excel files and create them the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same logic which we are using to generate any simple file in JAVA using File object.

Below code will generate excel file and write it into file

```
File file = new File("d://excelFile.xls"); //your file path to save it on drive
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
WritableWorkbook w = Workbook.createWorkbook(fos);

//Your code to add data to File

fos.close();
```

May this will help you.

Comment: Actually i have jsp file which i want to convert in xls.
`response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="
                    + "PendingDispatch_"+ft.format(date)+".xls");` here is the code which convert for client. i wnat to convert for server

Comment: what is the content of your excel file?

Comment: it is simple document